# Sqlalchemy union_all with paginate not working properly

Tags: python-3.x, flask-sqlalchemy

I have two queries 1. for not null values 2. for null values
I need to display first all not null values then all null values

```
query1 = db.session.query(Account).filter(Account.activation_date != null())
query2 = db.session.query(Account).filter(Account.activation_date == null())

final_query = query1.union_all(query2)
final_query = final_query.order_by(Account.account_name).paginate(
                paging['page'], paging['per_page'], error_out=False)
```

Ex.: suppose in database 1500 records, then i pass per_page=1500 its working properly.
if i pass per_page less than 1500 so its not working, its coming randomly.